# Can`t Redirect inside If statement in Servlet

Tags: java, redirect, servlets

I am working on a Web application and in my Servlet i do validation. If i have some empty input or something, i want it to redirect to the same page. But i am having some problem. If i try to make the redirect inside if statement (without else statement) it does not redirect, it would just go below and produce an error.

how could i make it work? without having multiple if/else statements.
Here is my simplified code:

```
   if (dateOfDelivery.equals(" ") || dateOfDelivery.equals("")) {
                String errorMsq = "Error create Order, enter return Date";
                log.error(errorMsq);
                new ErrorRedirect().sendRedirect(ErrorRedirect.ERROR_MAIN_MENU_URL + errorMsq, response);
   } else {
                LocalDate sqlDateOfDelivery = LocalDate.parse(dateOfDelivery, dateFormat);
                Long defaultPenalty = 0L;
                OrderValidation.redirectIfBookCountInStockZero(book, response);
                if (book.getCountInStock() == 0 || book.getCountInStock() < 0) {
                    String errorMsq = "Book count in stock equals zero!";
                    new ErrorRedirect().sendRedirect(ErrorRedirect.ERROR_MAIN_MENU_URL + errorMsq, response);
                } else {

                    Order order = Order.builder()....
   response.sendRedirect(allBooksList);
```

My `new ErrorRedirect().sendRedirect()` it is simple wrapper which i wrote.

Comment: Have you tried to return from handler after sending redirect?

Comment: @vasile_t  You my hero. You can add an answer and i will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return from handler after sending redirect, something like:

```
if (dateOfDelivery.equals(" ") || dateOfDelivery.equals("")) {
            String errorMsq = "Error create Order, enter return Date";
            log.error(errorMsq);
            new ErrorRedirect().sendRedirect(ErrorRedirect.ERROR_MAIN_MENU_URL + errorMsq, response);
            return "redirected...";
}
```

Comment: almost like this. it will accept only empty return, as the method is void. But your solution is worked.